# Perform segue from sub-ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3

At the moment I have a `ViewController` class containing a `UIScrollView`, within the scroll view I have another view controller, where I can currently receive gesture recognition. My goal is to be able to perform a segue to a different view controller, based on which subViewController I tap.

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0, width: self.view.frame.width, height:self.view.frame.height-106))
scrollView.delegate = self;      
self.view.addSubview(scrollView);

let subView11 = subView(nibName: nil, bundle: nil);
subView1.view.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: CGFloat(openReelHeight));
self.addChildViewController(subView1);
scrollView.addSubview(subView1.view);
subView.didMove(toParentViewController: self);
```

Then in the subView class I have a basic touch recognition function:

```
@IBAction func tapOnView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //change main View controller
}
```

Comment: show the code which you have tried..?

Comment: instead of posting the code in comment, you should edit the your question.

Comment: yeah, I realized that, the formatting was all off

Comment: what's in your subView class..?

Comment: It's just a template, I suppose I could have just used a UIView instead. It holds a few variables and displays some images and labels.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with view controller containment, especially if the child has any code unique to its views. It's a nice way of keeping the parent view controller from getting too bloated, with lots of logic for the various child view controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest letting the parent perform the segue. So you need a mechanism to let the child inform the parent that the button has been tapped. Here are two approaches:

1. The child view controller can define a protocol and then have its `@IBAction` for the button invoke that in the parent view controller.

   ```
   protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate {
       func child(_ child: ChildViewController, didTapButton button: Any)
   }

   class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

       @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
           if let parent = parent as? ChildViewControllerDelegate {
               parent.child(self, didTapButton: sender)
           }
       }

   }
   ```

   Clearly, the parent view controller needs to conform to that protocol:

   ```
   extension ViewController: ChildViewControllerDelegate {
       func child(_ child: ChildViewController, didTapButton button: Any) {
           // now segue to whatever you want
       }
   }
   ```
2. You can alternatively follow an explicit protocol-delegate pattern, rather than relying upon the view controller containment relationships of the `parent`:

   ```
   protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate: class {
       func didTapButton(_ sender: Any)
   }

   class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

       weak var delegate: ChildViewControllerDelegate?

       @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
           delegate?.didTapButton(sender)
       }

   }
   ```

   And then, when the parent adds the child, it would have to explicitly set the `delegate`:

   ```
   let child = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildViewController") as! ChildViewController
   addChildViewController(child)
   child.delegate = self

   // add the child's view to your view hierarchy however appropriate for your app

   child.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
   ```

   And, of course, the parent again has to conform to this protocol:

   ```
   extension ViewController: ChildViewControllerDelegate {
       func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
           // segue to next scene
       }
   }
   ```

Note, with both of these approaches, you can change your protocol's `func` to include whatever parameters you want (e.g. passing back contents of some `UITextField` or whatever). Likewise, you might use method names that make the functional intent of the child a little more explicit. I used somewhat generic method and protocol names because I don't know what the various children are doing.

Comment: thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for, however, could you explain exactly what a protocol is and how I might use it in the further?

Comment: A basic principle in programming is to keep different classes as loosely coupled as possible (i.e. the child shouldn't be programmed specifically to work with a particular parent class, because it's too easy to break the child if you make some change to the parent). So a protocol is, in effect, a contract between two loosely coupled classes to say "hey, child, you don't need to know anything specifically about the parent, beyond the fact that if it conforms to your protocol, you do know that it will implement this one method that you defined in your protocol."

Comment: So similar to an abstract class in Java?

Comment: Sort of, but without the notion of it being a part of a hierarchy where the concrete class is subclass of some virtual class. It's looser than that. It's merely stating that the class will implement certain prescribed methods and properties. See WWDC 2015 video [Protocol Oriented Programming](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/).